# Mongo and Java: Create indexes for aggregation framework

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

**Situation**: I have collection with huge amount of documents after map reduce(aggregation). Documents in the collection looks like this:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "appId" : ObjectId("1"),
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-04-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "name" : "GameApp",
        "user" : "test@mail.com",
        "type" : "game"
    },
    "value" : {
        "count" : 2
    }
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "appId" : ObjectId("2"),
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "name" : "ScannerApp",
        "user" : "newUser@company.com",
        "type" : "game"
    },
    "value" : {
        "count" : 5
    }
}

...
```

And I searching inside this collection with aggregation framework:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([match, project, group, sort, skip, limit]); // aggregation can return result on Daily or Monthly time base depends of user search criteria, with pagination etc...
```

**Possible search criteria:**

```
1. {appId, timestamp, name, user, type} 
2. {appId, timestamp}
3. {name, user}
```

I'm getting correct result, exactly what I need. But from optimisation point of view I have doubts about indexing.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to create indexes for such collection?
2. How I can create indexes for such object with complex **_id** field?
3. How I can do analog of **db.collection.find().explain()** to verify which index used?
4. And is good idea to index such collection or its my performance paranoia?

---

**Answer summarisation:**

- MongoDB creates index by `_id` field automatically but that is useless in a case of complex `_id` field like in an example. For field like: `_id: {name: "", timestamp: ""}` you must use index like that: `*.ensureIndex({"_id.name": 1, "_id.timestamp": 1})` only after that your collection will be indexed in proper way by `_id` field.
- For tracking how your indexes works with Mongo Aggregation you can not use `db.myCollection.aggregate().explain()` and proper way of doing that is:

db.runCommand({ 
        aggregate: "collection_name",
        pipeline: [match, proj, group, sort, skip, limit],
        explain: true 
    })

- My testing on local computer sows that such indexing seems to be good idea. But this is **require more testing** with big collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, indexes 1 and 3 are probably worth investigating.  As for explain, you can pass explain as an option to your pipeline.  You can find docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) and an example [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option)

Comment: I saw this doc but db.myCollection.aggregate([match, project, group, sort, skip, limit], {explain : true}) gives me cursor without info about indexes...
But how I can create indexes for this collection?

Comment: There's nothing special about those indexes.  You can find how to create them [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/).

Comment: if I will create indexes for collection like that: *.ensureIndex({"_id. appId": 1, "_id.timestamp": 1}) does it take effect with db.myCollection.aggregate()?

Comment: Yes.  Aggregation will try to use the indexes you've defined on a collection the same way a query will.

Comment: Further to @evanchooly response - your #2 is really a subset of #1 and does not need to be an independent index.