# MongoDB compound index with multi-key field and range query

Tags: mongodb

The question has been previously asked in another thread ([MongoDB - Multi-key and Compound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763074/mongodb-multikey-compound-index-need-help-understanding-bounds)) and there is currently no solution from MongoDB.   Has anyone developed a successful workaround either through indexing or document design?

Example document:

```
{
  timestamp: Timestamp(1234123123,0),
  values : [
     {field1:"somevalue", field2:"otherValue"},
     {field1:"somevalue2", field2:"otherValue2"}
  ]
}
```

Our index specifically is: `timestamp : -1, values.field2:1` and the explain shows that the lower bound of the timestamp is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

if you have complex object you need index values with defining path to this value, like that values.field2:1

```
db.collectionName.ensureIndex( { timestamp: -1}, {values.field2: 1} )
```

Also I had some kind of same question some time ago. Check out here: [Mongo and Java: Create indexes for aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389363/mongo-and-java-create-indexes-for-aggregation-framework)

Comment: We had already created the index in the manner that you suggested.